# Check for spaces using regex

Tags: php, regex, character

I'm using regex (I think that's what it's called - haha) to check my users' name to make sure it's valid. I want to make sure that the user doesn't have any characters. Just letters and spaces. I've got the only letters part down, but I can't get the spaces part fixed.

Here's what I'm using now..

```
if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z]/", " ", $name) != 0) {

        $errorlist = $errorlist."<li>You must enter a valid First and Last name (check for invalid characters)</li>";

}
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you probably could use `\s`

Comment: Can't use \s - that matches all whitespace characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a space to your regex pattern.  PS - your second parameter for preg_match() should probably be $name, right?  Is there a reason you were testing " "?

```
if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z ]/", $name) != 0) {
    $errorlist = $errorlist."<li>You must enter a valid First and Last name (check for invalid characters)</li>";
}
```

Comment: I didn't know it was that easy! Thanks!

Comment: @Fred - The reason you want to use a space character here instead of `\s` is that the latter would allow tabs and carriage returns in addition to spaces.

Comment: @StevenMoseley I deleted my question. I noticed it right after. Good call ;-) cheers

Comment: @StevenMoseley Would it also need to have a space after `a-z`?

Comment: @Fred - No. The pattern only requires a single representation of each character to match.  In this case, we're saying "match NOT (all characters between a and z, all characters between A and Z, and spaces)"